# Products weight with two decimals

Tags: product

Where should I edit in order to setup product weight with 2 decimals. Now the weight it showed in format as: 13.000 kilos. Those 3 zeros are useless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the theme you are using how and where the weight is outputted. I would advice you to turn on template hints on the front end to figure out where to edit the output of the weight.

Magento works by default with 4 decimals for weight (and price) and I would advice against editing the back end to accept just 2.

Another option would be to make sure under `Attributes` that the weight attribute is not displayed in product listing and create a second attribute called `weight_display`, type text, for example that is used on the frontend to show the weight of the product. This way Magento can use it's internal 4 decimal weight attribute and on the front end you can use your own attribute

Answer (score 0):

In database, weight attribute have backend_type set to decimal.

To change the decimal precision of attributes that have a backend_type set to decimal,

You have to change the type of value in this table :

```
catalog_product_entity_decimal
```

If you have not change yet, you should see :

```
decimal(12,4)
```

In your case, you have to replace with

```
decimal(12,2)
```

Then weight will be display with 2 decimals : (13.00 kilos) in admin, and in frontend